# Select a value from drop down using Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am having tough time in selecting value from drop down using C# binding of WebDriver. I have worked on neither C# nor WebDriver in past. I am using WebDriver - Selenium-dotnet2.0b3 with Visual Studio C# 2010 Express edition.
I have added WebDriver.Common, WebDriver.Firefox and WebDriver.Remote to my solution. I tried using this -

```
IWebElement dateOfBirth = webdriver.FindElement(By.Id("join_birth_day"));
List<IWebElement> dateOfBirthOptions = (List<IWebElement>)dateOfBirth.FindElement(By.TagName("option"));

foreach(IWebElement dateOfBirthOption in dateOfBirthOptions)  
{
    if (dateOfBirthOption.Equals("3"))
    {
        dateOfBirthOption.Select();
    }
}
```

But got to see error, when running my solution in NUnit

```
LiveCams.CreateAccount.createAccount:
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxWebElement' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]'.
```

And if I don't cast then would not be able to even build the solution.
I guess I am missing some thing trivial here. Any one who could guide me here?
Drop down selection used to be so simple in Selenium 1.0 :-/

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278281/how-to-using-webdriver-selenium-for-selecting-an-option-in-c

Comment: Nop it does not, I wonder which namespace has class - "SelectElement"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1)  Using a SelectElement as already commented - [How to select an option from drop down using Selenium WebDriver C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278281/how-to-using-webdriver-selenium-for-selecting-an-option-in-c)  The SelectElement belongs to the **OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI** namespace.

2)  You could also do something like this with css selectors:

```cs
WebElement dateOfBirth =  webdriver.FindElement(By.Id("join_birth_day"))
                              .FindElement(By.CssSelector("option[value='3']")).Select();
```

Comment: I am not able to get reference of SelectElement, Have I missed any DLL?

Comment: Its actually a part of OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement. I've updated the answer.

yes, double check you've imported all the dll's.

Comment: Got it now, thanks. and I am going to stick to css selection

Comment: Really this question should be flagged as a duplicate, not re-iterate your answer in another answer

Comment: This does not work at all for me. 'No overload for method 'Select' takes 0 arguments.'

Comment: It seems the Select() method is no longer available in FindElement object.

Comment: if you can't find reference to SelectElement, install this package: "selenium.support" on Nuget.

Answer (score 10):

To select an Option from Drop Down use the below code

1. To select a value based on Text

   ```
   new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""))).SelectByText("");
   ```
2. To select a value based on Value

   ```
   new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""))).SelectByValue("");
   ```
3. To select a value based on Index

   ```
   new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""))).SelectByIndex(0);
   ```

Comment: Not to be nit-picky here, but for those that may be confused, when Selecting by Index, you do not need quotes in SelectByIndex(), just an int.

Comment: This is now all covered in [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium-webdriver/6426/select-clas)

Answer (score 4):

Use the Following Class SelectElement defined in OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI namespace the word `Select` is already used in C# that is why its implementation is changed and class is named differently.

```
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the SelectElement class.
    //
    // Parameters: element - The element to be wrapped
    //
    public SelectElement(IWebElement element);
```

Create an object of this class and there is option of selection based on index, text and value.

```
    // Summary:
    //     Select the option by the index, as determined by the "index" attribute of
    //     the element.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   index:
    //     The value of the index attribute of the option to be selected.
    public void SelectByIndex(int index);

    // Summary:
    //     Select all options by the text displayed.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   text:
    //     The text of the option to be selected. If an exact match is not found, this
    //     method will perform a substring match.
    // Remarks:
    //     When given "Bar" this method would select an option like:
    //     <option value="foo">Bar</option>
    public void SelectByText(string text);

    // Summary:
    //     Select an option by the value.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   value:
    //     The value of the option to be selected.
    // Remarks:
    //     When given "foo" this method will select an option like:
    //     <option value="foo">Bar</option>
    public void SelectByValue(string value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTests {
    class DropDownListSelection {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://YourDDListpageURL.html");
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//Select"));
            //You can locate the element by using the ID / Name as well IList
            AllDropDownList = element.FindElements(By.XPath("//option"));
            int DpListCount = AllDropDownList.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < DpListCount; i++) {
                if (AllDropDownList[i].Text == "Coffee") {
                    AllDropDownList[i].Click();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(DpListCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer for proper code formatting.