# Selecting from dropdown-selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, drop-down-menu

How can I get Selenium to select from an option value from a dropdown ?

The HTML is below:

```
<select name="cboProxyMember" id="idProxyMember" onchange="selectMember(); return false">
 <option value="29">
 Text - Fullers Inns
 <option value="8840">
 Text - Turks Head
```

I have selected the element with no problem, using:

```
 var selectproxy = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("idProxyMember"));
 selectproxy.Click();
```

But how do I select the option ?

I have tried a find element by name and tagname but neither work.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for posting this late, Below code example will solve the issue, selecting from the dropdown.

```
var selectproxy = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("idProxyMember"));
selectproxy.Click();
var SelectOption = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement(selectproxy);
selectElement.SelectByText(<Define your option name which you want to 
select>);

For example: selectElement.SelectByText("Turks Head");
```

Comment: Yeah! The only answer in C#!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example in Python as I'm not familiar with the C# bindings, my apologies.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

selectproxy = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("idProxyMember"))
selectproxy.select_by_visible_text("Text - Fullers Inns")
selectproxy.select_by_value("29")
```

Comment: +1, the idea is the same in C# though - it's called the `SelectElement` within the `OpenQA.Selenium.Support` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("idProxyMember")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("Fullers Inns");
select.selectByValue("29");
```

Answer (score 0):

This posting describes how to select an option from a dropdown using C#.  The initial IWebElement you locate must be converted to a Select element before you can select options from it. [Select a value from drop down using Selenium WebDriver C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471515/webdriver-c-sharp-select-a-value-from-drop-down)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Try and avoid linking to tutorials/websites without a small sample of code as links can move or be deleted in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Correct you cant select by this because in your HTML,
```

It shows "onchange="selectMember();", Means ON selecting the any 
item from dropdown complete page has been changed. 
Thats why you have to use the switch to that Frame before 
selecting any value from dropdown.

driver.switchTo().frame(name_or_id);

Now select the value from dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Sample statements to open browser, load URL and select value from dropdown

```
static WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\(Path)\\IEDriverServer.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("EnterURLHere");          
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Select value1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("idProxyMember")));    
value1.selectByVisibleText("29");    //Select Character from dropdown list
```