# Get currently selected option in dropdown box in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have a dropdown similar to this one:

```
<select id="PlaceOfBirth">
    <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
    <option value="1">Somewhere</option>    
    <option value="2">Somewhere else</option>    
    <option value="3">somewhere else again</option>
</select>
```

In selenium now, I want to make sure that, on page load, `-- Please select --` is selected by default.

Googling through, [selecting by xpath and [selected="selected"]](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/msg/044db8f58aba94eb) looked promising, but, I can't use it because none of my `options` have selected attribute to start with.

So I thought, instead, I can just select the first element like so:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='PlaceOfBirth']/*[1]"));
//the actual xpath being //select[@id='PlaceOfBirth']/*[1]
```

Though this does return the first option nicely, it's not necessarily the selected one. How do I make sure the currently selected option is the one I want 
`(value="", text="-- Please select --")` please?

Thanks.

ps: I am using selenium webdriver
pps: I have come across various answers like `selectLocator`, etc but either they are php/java or I can't find them in my namespace...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5296364) for how to create a `SelectElement` in WebDriver. Once you have that, the `SelectedOption` property will enable you to verify what is selected on page load.

Comment: @Bryan, thanks so much! that did lead me to few things that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
var selectedItemText = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].options[arguments[0].selectedIndex].text;", element);
var selectedItemValue = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].options[arguments[0].selectedIndex].value;", element);
var selectedItemIndex = (long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].selectedIndex;", element);
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Anders, Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Hey Anders
Can you please help me here to get the same with Java?

Comment: Lowercase "e" for "ExecuteScript"?
You may just want to post a new question and link to this one, then someone that is familiar with WebDriver for Java can help you out.