# How to click on a text in a Container Column Container Using Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

HTML looks like below

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentColumnContent_PatientPanel" > 
    <span id="ctl00_ContentColumnContent_lblPatient" class="label required">
       Select a Patient:
    </span>

    <select name="ctl00$ContentColumnContent$ddlPatient" id="ctl00_ContentColumnContent_ddlPatient" class="select wide" size="10">
       <option value="0">**Delhi**</option>
       <option value="5422">Mumbai</option>
       <option value="326">Chennai</option>
    </select>

<span id="ctl00_ContentColumnContent_rfvPatient" style="color: red; visibility: hidden;">
   Field is required
</span>
</div>
```

I want to click on "Delhi".

Please guide me how to do this.

Comment: Please post proper html with tags and attributes.

Comment: <div id="ctl00_ContentColumnContent_PatientPanel">
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentColumnContent_lblPatient" class="label required">Select a Patient:</span>
                    <select name="ctl00$ContentColumnContent$ddlPatient" id="ctl00_ContentColumnContent_ddlPatient" class="select wide" size="10">
   <option value="0">Delhi</option><option value="1233">Mumbai</option>
      </select>
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentColumnContent_rfvPatient" style="color: red; visibility: hidden;">Field is required</span>
        </div>

Comment: @Vikas, Posted the HTML plz have a look

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Using Webdriver Selenium for selecting an option in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278281/how-to-using-webdriver-selenium-for-selecting-an-option-in-c)

Comment: Edit the question, don't add code into comments

Comment: @Vikas, I tried using XPath, but it's throwing error. Even for some other items it's saying not able to locate item. For those items I tried name/id. I am having issue for only some of the controls. Please guide for any suggestion.

Comment: Please post what all have you tried.

Comment: I have tried these 2 options,1--CssSelector
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#ctl00_ContentColumnContent_ddlPatient > option:nth-child(1)").Click();
2--XPath
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("//*[@id="ctl00_ContentColumnContent_ddlPatient"]/option[1]").Click();

Comment: Both CSS and XPath are throwing error

Comment: In the second option you are saying you used *xpath* but your code says *By.CssSelector*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work -

```
// select the drop down list
var patient = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$ContentColumnContent$ddlPatient"));
//create select element object 
var selectElement = new SelectElement(patient );

// select by text
selectElement.SelectByText("**Delhi**");
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas, it worked. Thanks a lot. And sorry for the confusion actually I copied and forgot to rename it as XPath. Will take care while posting any more queries.

Comment: No problem. I am glad it helped. Please select my answer as successful.