# Have same variable twice

Tags: c#, variables, webdriver

An error says that it is already defined a variable of `selectElement` when I  add a second dorpdownmenu to select

```
    SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Month")));
    selectElement.SelectByText("January");
```

here is any way to have 2 exact variables in a project of selenium with webdriver C#? (not in java)

Comment: Can you copy the error output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
            new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Month"))).SelectByText("January");
```

Solution discovered here:
[How to select an option from drop down using Selenium WebDriver C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278281/how-to-using-webdriver-selenium-for-selecting-an-option-in-c)

To Select an Option Via Text;

```
(new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""))).SelectByText("");
To Select an Option via Value:

 (new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""))).SelectByValue("");
```