# How do I find and select a dropdown value with Selenium using C# in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to locate an element within a dropdown list with Selenium. How can I do this? Attached are images which describe the situation. I want to do this using the IWebElement function.

I've tried using the following:

```
IWebElement Depart = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("///input[@name='fromPort' and @value='Sydney']"));
```

but it does not work!! How can I select Sydney from the drop-down list?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select an option from drop down using Selenium WebDriver C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278281/how-to-select-an-option-from-drop-down-using-selenium-webdriver-c)

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

If the dropdown is defined with select and option tag, then you can use the `SelectElement` class to select the value from the dropdown.

You can use any one of the method to select the value from the dropdown [Refer the Documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm)

**SelectByIndex** - Select an option by the index

**SelectByText** - Select an option by the text displayed.

**SelectByValue** - Select an option by the value.

You need to pass the dropdown element to the `SelectElement` class and can use any one of the above method

**Code:**

```
IWebElement Depart = driver.FindElement(By.Name("fromPort"));
SelectElement select=new SelectElement(Depart);
```

**Option 1:**

```
 select.SelectByText("Sydney");
```

**Option 2:**

```
 select.SelectByValue("Sydney");
```

**Option 3:**

```
 select.SelectByIndex(8);//Sydney value index is 8
```

Comment: @Novice_29: Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick button

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code for that:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


var selectElement = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("fromPort")));
selectElement.SelectByText("London");
```

Hope it helps you!