# XPath to select specific Dropdown value

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to select 'VxDev: InterAction Test Automation List' from the dropdown. The code is like below

```
<select name="intEmailListId" id="intEmailListId" style="min-width: 210px" data-selected-list="8589934864" class="list_selector">
                <option value="">** Please select a list **</option>

                <option value="">
                    --
                </option>
                <option value="my-contacts">
                    My contacts
                </option>
                <option value="">
                    --
                </option>


                    <option value="8589934952">
                        * 001 New List
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;</option>



                    <option value="8589934880">
                        VxDev: Hard Bounce List (QA team only)
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;</option>


                    <option value="8589934864" selected="">
                        VxDev: InterAction Test Automation List
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
```

And I tried below xpath which used to work is now not working

```
try
                    {
                        selectedList =
                            BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(
                                By.XPath(".//li[text()[contains(.,'" + listName + "')]]/input"));
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchElementException)
                    {
                        selectedList = BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(
                        //By.XPath(".//option[text()[contains(.,'" + listName + "')]]"));
                            By.XPath(".//option[starts-with(normalize-space(text()),'" + listName + "')]"));

                    }
```

Please help how to select the specific dropdown value? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe use css selector instead....By.Selector("#intEmailListId > option[value='8589934864']")...You will need to click it then...You can also use  SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(.By.Selector("#intEmailListId > option[value='8589934864']")) and then do one of selectElement.SelectByText("drop down visible Text here") or selectElement.SelectByValue("value of option here") or selectElement.SelectByIndex(index of option here)

Comment: what do you mean by *"is now not working"* ? What happen when you run the code?

Comment: When I run the code, the script is getting timedout. When I manually inspect the element using the above xpath, the list element is not getting selected in Chrome

Comment: @Tanya, just add `selectedList.Click();`

Comment: Please take a minute to fix the indent of the HTML. There are plenty of HTML beautifiers on the web that will help with that. Also fix the indent of your code so that it's easier to read. You need to post the full (relevant) error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select an option from drop down using Selenium WebDriver C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278281/how-to-select-an-option-from-drop-down-using-selenium-webdriver-c)

Comment: You are making this way harder than it needs to be. You should be using the `SelectElement` class. See the dup I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the problem is with your syntax. Try this:

```
try{
    selectedList = BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(.,'" + listName + "')]/input"));
    By.XPath("//li[contains(.,'" + listName + "')]/input"));
    //By.XPath("//li[contains(text(),'" + listName + "')]/input")); // you can try this as well
   }catch (NoSuchElementException){
          selectedList = BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(
          //By.XPath("//option[contains(.,'" + listName + "')]"); // OR
          //By.XPath("//option[contains(text(),'" + listName + "')]");
          By.XPath("//option[starts-with(normalize-space(text())='" + listName + "')]")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

```
String selectedList = BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[@value='8589934864']")).GetAttribute("value");
```

OR

```
String selectedList = BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[@value='8589934864']")).GetAttribute("innerText");
```