# LeanFT C# Selecting a Value From Drop Down List

Tags: c#, leanft

I'm having some trouble using Object Identification on a drop down list, what is being returned is this:

```
IListBox pricerBox= browser.Describe<IListBox>(new 
 ListBoxDescription
               {
                TagName = @"SELECT",
                Name = @"select"

            });
```

I would like to select a value from the drop down list and I tried using this as an example: [How to select an option from drop down using Selenium WebDriver C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278281/how-to-select-an-option-from-drop-down-using-selenium-webdriver-c) But didn't have any luck as I'm using LeanFT in C# MS VS.

When inspecting in Chrome, this is the list box element details:

```
<select tabindex="1" style="width: 150px;">
<option value="3">Mc1</option><option value="11">Mc2</option><option 
 value="17">Mc3</option><option value="21">Mc4</option><option 
 value="57">Mc5</option></select>
```

This is what I coded so far:

```
  //pricer box
           IListBox pricerBox= browser.Describe<IListBox>(new 
    ListBoxDescription
           {
               TagName = @"SELECT",
               Name = @"select"

           });
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            pricerBox.Click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at LeanFT's documentation for `IListBox`, the [`Select` function](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/NetSDKReference/webframe.html#HP.LFT.SDK~HP.LFT.SDK.Web.IListBox~Select.html) looks like what you're looking for.

```
pricerBox.Select("Mc3"); // No need to sleep before this
```